# How to check if webView can be scrolled?

Tags: android, webview

I found `WEbView.canScrollVertically(int direction)` method. Unfortunatly it does not support API 8. How can I achive simmilar functionality?

Comment: Do you **really need** it? I **never used** it.

Comment: What a weird comment !!?? I *really* need it too. Why do you ever doubt that OP does ? If you do think that it's useless, then at least give us alternatives. :/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By doing some programming stuff you can achieve like this:

```
webView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                if(webView.getHeight()<webView.getContentHeight()){
                    // webview is scrollable
                }else{
                    // webview is not scrollable
                }

            }
        });
```